# Can modules in Morea be marked as optional?

Tags: morea-framework

I'd like to add to my course materials, some additional modules which will be marked as **optional**.

By optional, I mean that they have content (mostly static, e.g., readings) and are probably not going to be covered directly during the course lectures.
However, I'd like them still to appear below the main modules, but somehow separated and marked differently as, well, optional.

I guess I could index them last and also add "(Optiona)" text, but just wondering if there is a better solution for presenting them, e.g. a separating line, a tag like the "coming soon" option, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple approach is to list these modules last (by using a high value for `morea_sort_order`) and then add an Optional label (by using `morea_labels`). Here's an example:

[image: optional module]

If you want to get fancier, then you could edit the `master/src/modules/index.md` file to customize the way the modules page is rendered.  If you go this way, you could put a dividing line between the required and optional modules, add some CSS to change the border color or background of the optional modules, or anything else you want to do.